# MS SQL - Get data from primary key's table

Tags: sql, select, key

Example:

Table: one
Column (PK): employee_ssn
Column: employee_active bit

Table: two
Column (pk): date
Column (FK): employee_ssn
Column: total_income
Column: total_expenses

--

Selecting data from table two:

### select * from two

In this example, how would I select for all employees with "1" for "employee_active"?

Answer (score 1):

You need to [JOIN](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) your tables together.

```
SELECT  two.employee_ssn, two.total_income, two.Total_Expenses
FROM    Two
        INNER JOIN One
            ON one.Employee_ssn = two.Employee_ssn
WHERE   One.employee_active = 1;
```

More links on Joins

- [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38578/1048425)
- [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)
- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)
- [SQL Authority](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/)
- [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this !!

```
select * from table1 a inner join table2 b 
on a.employee_ssn=b.employee_SSN 
where a.employee_active =1
```